# Azure Connection Fault Handling vs SqlException?

Tags: sql-server, exception, enterprise-library, azure-sql-database

I have some C# code that retries when it hits SqlExceptions, the code is running on a vanilla web server and talks to a Sql2k8 database, standard stuff.

I am interested in porting the code to a an Azure Web Role, and moving the database to SQL Azure. I discovered some EntLib stuff that seems to catch "connection faults" but I can't tell what the Enterprise Library code offers over my own bits.... SqlExceptions are SqlExceptions, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would like to add a couple of things on top of Grigori's answer.

The transient fault handling application block has a default retry policy for SQL Azure that will help you cover for the SqlExceptions only a SQL Database will throw (not a SQL Server database) that warrants a connection retry. The reason that's important is that you should only perform connection retries for SqlExceptions that warrant a retry. That's one of the benefits of using the application block.

However... as much as the application block can be very helpful, SqlExceptions are only one kind of errors you will get in the cloud: those generated by a SQL Database. You have other types of errors you may (will) need to catch for completeness that warrant connection retries, such as certain IO Exceptions that are the result of the load balancer or other intermediate proxy layer that's sitting between you and SQL Database.  There is no authoritative source on this information; just personal experience. The good news however is that there is a way (or I should say there used to be a way with the original retry framework) to customize the application block to include the kinds of exceptions you want the retry policy to handle. Since I haven't used the latest versions, please do very this claim... just in case things have changed.

So the application block offers a flexible way to manage your connection retry policies regardless of the SQL database engine you are connecting to and with good control over the list of exceptions you actually want to retry on. It might be an overkill for applications that have very centralized connection logic and only deal with SQL Databases, but it is a very powerful framework.

Comment: So you are saying that I can use the Transient Fault App Block for developing with an on-premises SQL Server instance, because it catches on-premise errors like SqlExcp and also Azure-specific ones? Interesting.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be referring to the [Transient Fault Handling Application Block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh680934%28PandP.50%29.aspx) that we shipped as a part of the Enterprise Library Integration Pack for Windows Azure. It includes detection strategies for not only SQL Azure, but also for Windows Azure Storage, Caching and Service Bus plus an extensible  set of retry strategies. The idea is to have a consistent retry behavior across multiple technologies used.

Sure, you can use your own detection code if all you care are SqlExceptions.